# How to unit test TypeScript files with test runner in a webpack project

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, karma-runner, webpack, ts-loader

I have the following setup:

1. Build process with webpack and ts-loader
2. Wanting to use test
   runner such as Karma to unit test the TS files

How do I best unit test TypeScript files with test runner in this webpack project? Its obvious to me how to do this with  js projects, but need a proven workflow for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate entry point for your test files in webpack, or you can compile ts before running webpack. I'd typically go for the latter

You can compile ts projects with the command `tsc -p .` and it will convert all `.ts` files to `.js` ones. Then you can get rid of the `ts-loader` and just treat everything as a js file.

Comment: Note that if you also need `babel-loader` or something similar, you should go with the former.